# How to email SalesForce users temporary password by using API?

Tags: api, soap, salesforce

I am using SOAP Partner API and I have a Developer edition. I am creating users by using API. And upon creation of users I want to email these users temporary password which they can use to login to SalesForce.

This is my code:

```
SaveResult[] results = connection.create(new SObject[] { user });

if (results[0].isSuccess())
{
out.println("Created user: " + results[0].getId());

//connection.setPassword(results[0].getId(), "password");
ResetPasswordResult rpr = connection.resetPassword(results[0].getId());
String result = rpr.getPassword();
  System.out.println("The temporary password for user ID " + results[0].getId()
        + " is " + result);
}
else
{
out.println("Error: " + results[0].getErrors()[0].getStatusCode() + 
                   ":" + results[0].getErrors()[0].getMessage());
}
```

This is the output I am getting in console:

```
The temporary password for user ID 005E0000000MwkZIAS is ucQD2PADs
```

However, the user is NOT receiving any password. :-(

Thanks,

Wap Rau

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you build & pass an [EmailHeader](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/sforce_api_header_emailheader.htm) in your soap request you can control what types of emails will get sent from your request.

It looks like you're using WSC, so you can add this call before calling resetPassword, which will enabled emails being sent to users. This should then send the standard reset password email.

```
connection.setEmailHeader(false, false, true);
```

Answer (score -1):

use this class to send out an email. include the pwd variable in the string you want to send the user. there's an example that spells everything out

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_email_outbound.htm

Comment: He is calling this from the API - if he could utilize Apex code, then the best course of action would be to use a call to `System.resetPassword(userId, true)`, which automatically sends an email to the user with a password reset link in it. Creating an outbound email in code would be overkill.